# php - upload file - filterting types to upload

Tags: php

```
<?php
if (($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] == "image/gif")
  || ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
  || ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] == "image/png" )
  && ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] < 10000))
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],
    "http://www.nhl-statistics.com/scripts/upload" . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
  }
else
  {
  echo "Files must be either JPEG, GIF, or PNG and less than 10,000 kb";
  }
```

no matter what i enter it seems to go to the else statement.

Comment: Besides Unicron's useful comment above, note the logical operator precedence: your AND  is bound to the last OR. Use more parentheses?

Comment: **Watch out!**  Those MIME types are provided by the user, and may be complete lies.  If you're using PHP 5.3, use [`finfo_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) to grab the *real* MIME type of the file.  If you're not using 5.3, you may be able to use [`mime_content_type`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) instead.

Comment: `move_uploaded_file()` should NOT be used to move the uploaded file to a URL - that's doing yet another upload, which is most likely NOT what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size is in bytes, not kilobits, you're only allowing files under the size of 78kb/10kB to be uploaded, but your echo says that files up to 10,000kb can be uploaded.

You might be uploading too large files.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the content of `$_FILES`?

Use `var_dump($_FILES);` to see what values you get, that might help you pinpoint your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fix this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], "path/to/upload/folder" . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```